# Rotate pseudo element around its center?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I created a simple tree menu.  The items that toggle use JQuery to show their children and toggle a class of "open".

I have a ":before" plus sign on the item, and when open it rotates 135 degrees to an x, see animated gif:

[image]

As you can see, it rotates "up". I want it to rotate around its center(which I thought was the default).  Here's my code:

```
.nav-header {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:before {
        content: '+';
        font-size: 23px;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        -ms-transition: all .3s;
        -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
    }
    &.open {
        &:before {
            -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            -moz-transform-origin: center center;
            -ms-transform-origin: center center;
            -o-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
            transform: rotate(135deg);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `transform-origin: center center;`?

Comment: Just a wild guess but what about using `middle middle` here: `transform-origin: middle right;`

Comment: yes, tried center center, 50% 50%, etc.

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Try `transform-origin: center center;`

EDIT: Need vendor-specific prefixes:

```
-moz-transform-origin: center center;
-webkit-transform-origin: center center;
-o-transform-origin: center center;
-ms-transform-origin: center center;
transform-origin: center center;
```

EDIT 2:

Check out this fiddle to see it operating in action: http://jsfiddle.net/B226E/18/

Comment: Tried that first, gets the result above.

Comment: Check out the link I sent you. Seems like there are some vendor specific prefixes needed for various browsers. Also updated my answer.

Comment: Also, I don't think it matters in your case since the X is so small, but the layout of the rest of the page is determined before the element is rotated, so if it was large and/or oddly shaped, it might overlap other elements.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle where this is working. Looks like we need more info. Something about your html/css/js is mucking with things, because the styles work as advertised in my example. EDIT: had a thought: use the DOM inspector in your browser (F12 in Chrome and IE I think) and see if the `:before` element is moving at all due to your expand logic. It may be that it is rotating about it's center, but something else is moving the center.

Comment: Mine works just like yours.  I think its just the way the "plus" sign looks.  I wound up using a glyphicon.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is it now:

[image]

I am using a bootstrap glyphicon, added some padding on its right and shifted the center 10%:

```
.nav-header {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    &:before {
        content: '\2b';
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        padding-right: 3px;
        font-weight: normal;
        display: inline-block;
        color: @brand-primary;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        -ms-transition: all .3s;
        -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 40% center;
        -moz-transform-origin: 40% center;
        -ms-transform-origin: 40% center;
        -o-transform-origin: 40% center;
        transform-origin: 40% center;
    }
    &.open {
        &:before {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
            transform: rotate(135deg);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#element:hover { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  }
```

Comment: I was trying to turn the + into an x